# Highlighting Menu Bar in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, menubar

I have a Visual Studio 2010 and when I added a NEW project, VS gives me default css and UI themes. I have 6 aspx pages. Now whenever user is going into some specific page, I want the menu bar of that page to get highlighted so that user will know which page he/she is.

I have a page called: CommSetup.aspx. In the page_load I have written this code:

And in the master page I changed this:

> In code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (MenuItem item in NavigationMenu.Items)
        {
            var navigateUrlParams = item.NavigateUrl.Split('/');
            if (Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf(navigateUrlParams[navigateUrlParams.Length - 1]) != -1)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

> Markup:

```
 <body runat ="server" clientidmode ="Static" id = "MasterBody">
    <form runat="server">......
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server"  StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass ="Selected"      CssClass="menu" .....
```

This is what I added in Site.css:

```
div.menu ul li a.Selected
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of doing exactly what you're asking for using CSS:

http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/highlighting-current-page-with-css

You should be able to achieve that using static ID naming on your controls (instead of letting ASP.NET assign the ID value to each control).

**EDIT:**
To get this to work with a master page, change the `<body>` tag in your master page to:

```
<body runat="server" clientidmode="Static" id="MasterBody">
```

Then in the Page_Load of each page, you can overwrite the id for each page (the master page in my example is of type `SiteMaster`):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control c = Page.Master.FindControl("MasterBody");
    if (c != null)
    {
        c.ID = "Page1";
    }
}
```

## Update (2):

I tried running Farzin's example and it didn't seem to work, so here is what I was able to verify worked for me (you won't need the `Page_Load` from before in your content pages):

**Site.master**

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" ...>
    <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="selected" />
    ...
</asp:Menu>
```

**Site.master.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (MenuItem item in NavigationMenu.Items)
    {
        item.Selected = Page.ResolveUrl(item.NavigateUrl).ToLowerInvariant() == Request.Path.ToLowerInvariant();
    }
}
```

**Styles/Site.css**

```
div.menu ul li a.selected
{
    /* put your style definition here */
}
```

Comment: Will this technique work when his navigation is in a master page, as it should be?

Comment: What's not working, setting the id of your `<body>` tag on each page, or getting the styles to apply correctly to the menu items?

Comment: @Joel: I made the changes like you said. But my bar is not getting highlighted!

Comment: Hmm, I had assumed an asp:Menu would allow you to assign the ID on each MenuItem, but it turns out a MenuItem doesn't inherit from `System.Web.UI.Control` so it has no ID, and the CSS selectors rely on each menu item having a unique id. At this point, it looks like your options are 1) Create your menu direclty in HTML -or- 2) Follow Farzin's example below

Comment: @Joel: I tried exactly what you said. See my update. But it seems like it is not working... :(

Comment: If you view the source of your page and find the HTML for your menu, does the link for the current page show something like `<a class="level1 selected"...>` ? That will tell you if the problem is in your CSS or in correctly selecting the MenuItem.

Comment: <ul class="level1">

  <li><a class="level1" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li><li><a class="level1 selected" href="About.aspx">About</a></li>

 </ul>

Comment: This is what I got from source code. So I am guessing the problem is in the CSS?

Comment: Yep, looks that way. I notice you've defined `StaticSelectedStyle-CssClass ="Selected"` but ASP.NET is rendering it as `selected` on the page. You could try changing it to lower case in your CSS definition as well, not sure which if any browsers are case sensitive on CSS class names.

Answer (score 1):

You should parse current url in Master page (code behind) and assign different css clss to menu item that belongs to current url.

```
        foreach (MenuItem item in NavigationMenu.Items)
        {
            var navigateUrlParams = item.NavigateUrl.Split('/');
            if(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf(navigateUrlParams[navigateUrlParams.Length - 1]) != -1)
            {
                item.Selected = true;
            }
        }
```

just put this code in Form_Load event of your main master page (code behind)

Comment: I added this code to my MasterPage Code Behind. Is is not working. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: I started a new asp.net application like you and wrote this code. every thing was right. 
if you add this code to your code behind of master page and your solution was build successfully, it should work.
check your navigation menu name, it may differ from mine.

Comment: I opened up new ASP.NET Web App. Added your code in Master Code Behind in Page_Load event. It is not working. Like if I am going to About.aspx page, the 'About' menu is not getting highlighted :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ASP.NET Site Navigation functionality.  Scott Mitchell has put out one of the definitive articles on it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121516/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111605-1.aspx).