# Tab Menu color not changing on the selected tab

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I am messed up with horizontal tab menu.Could you please help me out from this ??
What i want in the menu,suppose when i clicked one of the tab menu link,the color of the tab menu should change and be stick with that color too when the selected tab is active.
Or you can get it like this that I want the menus exactly like on stackoverflow.com

Comment: provide link in website ya code

Comment: this is html code--
<div id="ddcolortabs">
<ul>
<li class="active" ><a href="Home.aspx" title="Home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href="About_Us.aspx" title="About Us"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
<li ><a href="Weddings.aspx" title="Weddings"><span>Weddings</span></a></li>
<li><a href="Services.aspx" title="Services"><span>Services</span></a></li> 
<li><a href="Gallery.aspx" title="Gallery"><span>Gallery</span></a></li> 
<li><a href="Contact_Us.aspx" title="Contact Us"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

Comment: You can use http://jsfiddel.net to provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#ddcolortabs li.active a span, #ddcolortabs li:hover a{ background-color: #f90;  color:#F00; text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: <style type="text/css">
#ddcolortabs{
margin-left: 4px;
margin-top:29px;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
background: transparent;
voice-family: "\"}\"";
voice-family: inherit;
padding-left: 5px;
}
#ddcolortabs ul{
font: bold 13px Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}
#ddcolortabs li{
display:inline;
margin:0 5px 0 0;
padding:0;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
  .ddcolortabs li:hover, .ddcolortabs li.active {
        background-color: #f90;
    }
as you can see style i applied . i think i used span that is why.can you send me the style or menu style like on stackoverflow.com

Comment: #ddcolortabs a{
float:left;
color: white;
background:#8B0000;
margin:0 2px 0 0;
padding:0 0 1px 3px;
text-decoration:none;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#ddcolortabs a span{
float:left;
display:block;
/*background: transparent url(media/color_tabs_right.gif) no-repeat right top;*/
background:#8B0000;
padding:6px 15px 6px 12px;
}
#ddcolortabs a span {
float:none;
}
#ddcolortabs a:hover{
background-color: #008B8B;
}
#ddcolortabs a:hover span{
background-color: #008B8B;
}
#ddcolortabs #current a, #ddcolortabs #current span{ /*currently selected tab*/
background-color: #008B8B;
}
rest css is it

</style>

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below link where solution with the same question has been provided :

[Highlighting menu bar in asp.net web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518118/highlighting-menu-bar-in-asp-net-web-application)